# How to create plugin for observer Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin

- I have one **Observer** in my custom module.
- I want to create **Plugin for that observer**.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right controller or observer path in your **di.xml** file as per the syntax mention here :

```
<config>
    <type name="{ObservedType}">
        <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{PluginClassName}" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

- **type name:** Enter name of a class or interface that needs to be
  followed.
- **plugin name:** An arbitrary plugin name that identifies a plugin. Also
  used to merge the configurations for the plugin.
- **plugin type:** Fill the name of a plugin’s class or its virtual type.
  You can refer the following naming convention for this field:
  \Vendor\Module\Plugin\Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to **di.xml** your plugin.

```
<type name="Your\Observer\Namespace">
    <plugin name="your_plugin_name" type="Your\Plugin\Class" />
</type>
```

Then you can create methods like beforeExecute afterExecute etc.